# Hbase Filters in Apache Phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, nosql

I am searching Hbase prefix filter in Apache Phoenix, is it available in phoenix?
My rowkey like 12345_@_)*6 now I want to run below Hbase scan in Apache Phoenix:-

scan 'tablename',{FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('12345_@')"}

Answer (score 0):

Use sql [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator: `select * from tablename where yourrowkey like '12345_@%'`
Phoenix will translate into filter for you.